# Breaking a long PHP **for** statement into multiple lines

Tags: php, for-loop, long-lines

In PHP **for** loop starts with

```
for (init counter; test counter; increment counter)
```

which can form quite a long line. 
 What is the best way to break it into shorter parts?

Example:

```
for ($currentLine = fgets ($fileToAnalyse); ! preg_match("^0 @Individual ", $currentLine); $currentLine = fgets($fileToAnalyse)) {/*...*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the specific example you are using the wrong loop. You do not know how many times you will need to iterate, therefore, the right loop would be `while`. You would not have a problem with too long line either.

```
$currentLine = fgets($fileToAnalyse);

while(!preg_match("^0 @Individual ", $currentLine)) {
    // code...
    $currentLine = fgets($fileToAnalyse);
}
```

Typically with for loop you should hardly ever get very long lines, since it is most often used with definite iteration for a known number of times.

But to shorten the `for` loop in general, you could do some weird stuff like exporting the definition of variable outside of the first line (**which I would not recommend**) like:

```
$currentLine = fgets ($fileToAnalyse);
for (;! preg_match("^0 @Individual ", $currentLine);) {
    /*...*/
     $currentLine = fgets($fileToAnalyse)
}
```

Comment: Does your answer mean that splitting **for** is impossible? (maybe my example wasn't deliberate enough ;)

Comment: @mja well the second snipped shows a way to shorten a **for** loop. Unless I do not understand the question?